# As challenging as it maybe

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence, sentence-meaning

Please suggest how to correct this sentence, particularly to fit in the bold part

However, ****, it is still necessary to provide solutions with the optical mouse as most existing computers use it.

Comment: "Maybe" is two words here: "may be".

Comment: Thanks Isabel, any other thing you notice weird about the sentence

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: Maybe a comma after "mouse".

Comment: Good job, Isabel. 

@Liwei What do you think sounds weird about it? 

To check the *maybe* you can test if it would work with *might be*. If it does that tells you it should be *may     be* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *However, as challenging as it maybe [sic], it is still necessary to provide solutions with the optical mouse as most existing computers use it.*

Here is one possible alternative to the sentence you provided:

> However, though solutions to the optical mouse problem may present us with challenges, the solutions are needed, since almost all modern computers accommodate the optical mouse.

Granted, my version is significantly longer than yours, but my version provides the clarity your version seems to lack. By the way, your "maybe" should have been "may be," hence the [sic].